# Unable to get the correct screenshot of element using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I am attempting to pull the table out of this https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/

[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
extension = r'cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx' 

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension(extension)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')   

url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/'
xpath = '//*[@id="usa_table_countries_today"]'  

driver.get(url);
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
    )
except:
    print("error")
    driver.close()
finally:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    element.screenshot_as_png("test.png")
    driver.close()
```

I get the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\someUser\PycharmProjects\project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
> (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
> File "C:\Users\someUser\PycharmProjects\project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
> raise err
> File "C:\Users\someUser\PycharmProjects\project\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
> sock.connect(sa)
> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I also have attempted to use this code to get the table.

```
finally:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    location = element.location;
    size = element.size;
    driver.save_screenshot("pageImage.png");
    x = location['x'];
    y = location['y'];
    width = location['x'] + size['width'];
    height = location['y'] + size['height'];
    im = Image.open('pageImage.png')
    im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))
    im.save('element_image.png')
    driver.close()
```

But the above code gets the wrong section of the page.

[image]

To troubleshoot that I also attempted with and without adding uBlock origin to selenium.
In both cases, the issue persists.

Any advice or help to get me going in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code - Have increased the page height to get a full page snapshot. This covers your table also.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def test_fullpage_screenshot():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/")
    time.sleep(5)

    # the element with longest height on page
    ele = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="usa_table_countries_today"]')
    total_height = ele.size["height"] + 1000

    driver.set_window_size(1920, total_height)  # the trick
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.save_screenshot("screenshot1.png")
    driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_fullpage_screenshot()
```

Not - You can increase/decrease the height as per your requirement.